# Install a package to a docker container (managed by dokku)

Tags: plugins, docker, dokku

I have a hard time understanding where is the right place to place a code that will install the needed packages for the given docker container managed by dokku.

We have a scala application and, unfortunately, we need to have one shell call that is dependent on an environment. I would like to install the given package for the given container using "apt-get install". Right now I am using a custom plugin with a file named "post-release-build". However, I don't have the permission to install anything in that phase.

Basically, my script that should be invoked looks like this (based on a dockerfile that is available online):

```
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y build-essential xorg libssl-dev libxrender-dev wget gdebi
    wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
    gdebi --n wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
    echo "-----> wkhtmltox installed!"
```

Is there a way how to make it work? I would also prefer to have such a file somewhere in the application so I don't need to setup environment before pushing the app (in the future).

EDIT:

I have found a plugin that should be capable of installing packages using apt-get (https://github.com/F4-Group/dokku-apt) however, I am a little bit unlucky because it downloads a package that is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since just downloading with apt-get will download a package that fails, I investigated deeper into dokku and came out with a new plugin that should install the package for you.

I have created a script, documented how to use it and licenced it over MIT license so feel free to use it. Hopefully it will save you the time I had to spend realizing what is going on.

URL: https://github.com/mbriskar/dokku-wkhtmltopdf